# Comments withoug user information facebook graph version 2.11

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When trying to get the feeds from facebook with comment with this query:

feed?fields=id,from{id,name,link},message,link,type,created_time,source,caption,description,name,story,picture,full_picture,shares,object_id,status_type,likes.summary(true).limit(0),comments.filter(stream).summary(true).order(reverse_chronological){id,attachment,created_time,from{id,name,category,link},like_count,message}

returns the comments author information up to version 2.10 but it does not return that info when using version 2.11. Any ideas of how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using an App Access Token. In order to get the user info, you need to use a Page Token now. Of course you need to manage the Page to get a Page Token. Read about this in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#gapi-90

Comment: is it just me or now that gdpr came into effect, there are absolutely NO data about the commenting user at all, even if you have a page token. you may have info about a user only when he logs into your app. can someone prove/disprove it?